# Minimizing infrastructure code surface for NodeJS microservices and libraries

Tags: microservices, node.js, github, source-code, code-reuse

My company has about 200 repos for microservices and libraries that we share. It's largely been great, but it's hard to keep DRY at the organizational level. We'll often have a large amount of `package.json`, `webpack.config.js`, `.babelrc`, `.github/workflows` and similar infrastructure-level code that gets copied in though templates or copy/pasted from different GitHub repos.

Obviously a great way of minimizing duplication in source code is breaking code out to a library and installing it as a separate package. What's the best way to keep infrastructure code DRY?

I can think of a few options:

### Copy/paste

When creating a repo, just copy/paste another repo's infrastructure code over. Simple.

#### Pros

- Simplest approach when writing
- Explicit dependencies
- Effectively freezing code

#### Cons

- Lots of manual maintenance
- Code surface increases, abstraction decreases
- Requires developers parse through lots of (possibly) unfamiliar code

### GitHub templates

Use GitHub templates to create new repos. Keep templates up to date. Possibly update repos via a script to pull template updates.

#### Pros

- Slightly more structured than copy/pasting
- Provides an ideal standard for other repositories

#### Cons

- Still requires lots of manual upkeep
- Functionally similar cons to copy/pasting

### Include from parent repository

Add your new repo as a submodule of some other parent repo that contains infrastructure code. Either reference parent infrastructure or automatically copy parent code over (e.g. at build time).

#### Pros

- Single source of truth for infrastructure code
- Explicit dependency tracking

#### Cons

- Requires strong dependent relationship between parent and child repo
- Change to parent repo could break multiple children easily

### Include as submodules

All infrastructure dependencies reference external repos that contain the deps. Potentially version-pinned to commit hashes.

#### Pros

- Single source of truth for infrastructure code
- Explicit **versioned** dependency tracking

#### Cons

- (afaik) no readily-available tools to manage this
- Dealing with submodules is not fun.
- (afaik) Not possible to grab one file from one revision of a separate repo

Have I missed any major pros/cons? What other ways would you minimize code surface of scaffolding/infrastructure code?

Comment: Since it appears to be infrastructure based stuff, is it possible to change your build pipeline to work with separate microservices instead of each microservice managing its own deployment?  (For example, microservice `A` may be an input to the infrastructure build pipeline).  Though this sounds to be in contention with the microservice methodology, it may be worthwhile to separate the build pipeline and the code if the majority of microservices are deployed the same way.

Comment: Yeah, that's a possibility. though, as you said, that sounds more monolithic than microservice-ey. I suppose the tendency towards setup code duplication is a core flaw of microservices. Still looking for a better approach that fits the microservice bill instead of becoming more monolithic, though.

Comment: From your question, can you elaborate on what the downsides are, the "copy+paste" one is obvious, but to filter out undesirable answers can you say why any of the solutions you provide are not good?

Comment: Good call. I've updated the post with a small pros/cons list for each approach I could think of.